# Multivariable Calculus - second derivate using chain rule

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y,z) = g(2x+y-z,x+2y-z)$ which $g(u,v)$

$f_{y}=g_{u}(u,v)* u_{y} + g_{v}(u,v)*v_{y}$

$f_{y}=g_{u}(u,v) + 2g_{v}(u,v)$

We want $f_{yz}$ and I have no idea how to find the 2nd derivate using the chain rule.

for reference the answer is,
$f_{yz} = -g_{uu} - g_{uv} - 2g_{vu} - 2g_{vv} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that $g_u$ and $g_v$ follow the "tree diagram" of $g$. So,

$$f_{yz} = \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \, (g_u) + 2 \, \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \, (g_v)$$

$$f_{yz} = g_{uu} \, u_z + g_{uv} \, v_z + 2 \, g_{vu} \, u_z + 2 \, g_{vv} \, v_z$$

$$f_{yz} = - g_{uu} - g_{uv} - 2 \, g_{vu} - 2 \, g_{vv} $$

Comment: Could you draw the tree for me for 2nd derivative so i can better please? Would appreciate it alot

Comment: It's exactly the same for $g$. All of the three functions, $g$, $g_u$ and $g_v$, are functions of $u=2x+y-z$ and $v=x+2y-z$.